# no matches for /, Kind=NetworkPolicy

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I want to set a deny-all-egress policy on a namespace

Here is the yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress-namespace
  namespace: myns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

This gives me the following error

```
error: unable to recognize "deny-all-egress-namespace.yaml": no matches for /, Kind=NetworkPolicy
```

I am on version 1.7 of the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NetworkPolicy is under `networking.k8s.io` group with `v1` version.

Try like this.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: default-deny-egress-namespace
  namespace: myns
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels: {}
  policyTypes:
  - Egress
```

> *Engress* introduced in Kubernetes v1.8

And also above NetworkPolicy structure is supported by v1.8+

Check the [documentation](https://v1-7.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/network-policies/)

Comment: Yeah I tried that ,!it gives me another error “ IUnknown policytype”

Comment: let me check. give me time

Comment: kubernetes version?

Comment: I think your Kubernetes version is below v1.8

Comment: Oh! yes I am on 1.7! Is there a way to do that with 1.7?

Comment: No idea. may be not.